# CheckboxSelectionModel : How to check rows by default?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an EditorGridPanel with a CheckboxSelectionModel.  In the Ext.data.Source binded to this grid, I have a boolean value saying if the Checkbox of the rows should be checked by default or now.

How can I have a list that appears by default with the default Checkbox values correctly set, this based on the data value ?

Thanks in advance,

CB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant Ext.data.Store, you can do it by passing a filtered version of the store as the first parameter to CheckboxSelectionModel.selectRecords, preferably in the EditorGridPanel's show event:

```
panel.addListener('show', function() {
  this.getSelectionModel().selectRecords(this.getStore().filter('isset', 'true'));
});
```

Comment: this does not work for me, it just filters the store itself, but does not return the records based on the filters

Comment: instead of the `filter` method, you should use the [`query`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-query) method!

Comment: Well, keep in mind that this question and answer came in 2009, which was ExtJS 2.0/early 3.0. Things have probably changed in ExtJS in the interim.

Comment: idd it has, but the documentation regarding the `CheckBoxSelectionModel` is still rather poor. And that won't change now since they have moved on to version 4.

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer I'd upvote an answer that used query() instead ;)